# Angular 4 get value of input (timepicker) onBlur (focusOut)

Tags: angular, compare, timepicker, angular-reactive-forms, onblur

I have two time fields but I can't get their values to compare them. All I get is `undefined`! I want to get the value as soon as the field is left (focusout).
Here is my .ts code:

```js
isMeridian = false;
showSpinners = false;
timeStart: any;
timeSegment: any;   

onKeyTime(event) {
  console.log("onKeyTime :" + this.mySummaryForm.value.startTime);
  this.timeStart = this.mySummaryForm.value.startTime;   //event.target.value;
  console.log("select+++startTime : " + this.timeStart);
  console.log("change+++segTime : " + this.timeSegment);
}

onKeySeg(event) {
  console.log("onKeySeg : " + this.mySummaryForm.value.segmentTime3);
  this.timeSegment = this.mySummaryForm.value.segmentTime3;
  console.log("select---startTime : " + this.timeStart);
  console.log("change---segTime : " + this.timeSegment);
}

checkTimeValue() {
  console.log("checkTimeValue :");
  if((this.timeSegment < this.timeStart)) {
    console.log("a : " + this.timeSegment  + " > " + this.startTime);   
    // alert("good choice!");
  }
  else {
    console.log("b : " + this.startTime  + " < " + this.timeSegment);
    // alert("time segment should be later than start time.");
  }
}
```

Here is my .html code:

```html
<form [formGroup]="mySummaryForm" (ngSubmit)="submitMe(mySummaryForm)">    
  <label for="startTime"> Start time :      {{mySummaryForm.value.startTime |date: 'shortTime' | json}} 
    <timepicker formControlName="startTime" (ngModel)="startTime" [showMeridian]="isMeridian" [showSpinners]="showSpinners" (keyup)="onKeyTime($event)" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" #startTime required></timepicker>
  </label> 
  <label for="segmentTime3">Segment time : {{mySummaryForm.value.segmentTime3  |date: 'shortTime' | json}}
    <timepicker formControlName="segmentTime3" (ngModel)="segmentTime3" [showMeridian]="isMeridian" [showSpinners]="showSpinners" (keyup)="onKeySeg($event)" (focusout)="checkTimeValue()" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" #segmentTime3 required></timepicker>
  </label>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `[ngModel]` instead of `(ngModel)`?

Comment: Where is `mySummaryForm` set? perhaps you are setting the wrong values to `timeStart` and `timeSegment` in your onKey methods

Comment: @LLai : updated the form. timeStart and timeSegment are just temporary variables that will hold value as soon as the field has a value.

Comment: @ConnorsFan :  I am using formGroup.

Comment: You have a lot of unneccessary output events here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-bdu5e8?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the time is empty on page load. It is filled after and I want to get the value as soon as the time is set so I can compare them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I endup doing :

my .ts code

```
onChangeStart(event, label) {
    console.log("EVENT : " + event);    
    if (label == 'start_time')  {
        this.timeStart = event;
    }
  }

  onChangeSeg(event, label, index) {
    if (label == 'segmentTime3')  {
    this.timeSegment = event;
    console.log("this.timeSegment : " + this.timeSegment);
    }
    if (this.timeSegment > this.timeStart) {
        console.log(this.timeSegment + " > " +this.timeStart);
    }
    else {
        console.log(this.timeSegment + " < " +this.timeStart);
        alert("the segment time is wrong ! The segment time should be later than the start time. ");
    }
  }
```

my .html code

```
<label for="startTime"> Start time :  
     <timepicker formControlName="start_time" (ngModel)="start_time" [showMeridian]="isMeridian" [showSpinners]="showSpinners" (ngModelChange)="onChangeStart($event, 'start_time')" #start_time required></timepicker>
 </label> 
  <label for="segmentTime3">Segment time : 
      <timepicker formControlName="segmentTime3" (ngModel)="segmentTime3" [showMeridian]="isMeridian" [showSpinners]="showSpinners" (ngModelChange)="onChangeSeg($event, 'segmentTime3', i)" #segmentTime3 required></timepicker>
  </label>
```

There might be a better option but this works for me.